# If $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$, find $f(0)+2\lambda$.

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

If the function
$$ 
f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(1-\cos(1-\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}-x)))(1+x)^n+\lambda\sin((n-\sqrt{n^2-8n})x)}{x^2(1+x)^n+x} ; x\ne0
$$
(the value of $f(0)$ is unknown) is continuous at $x=0$, find $f(0)+2\lambda$.

My reasoning is as follows... If $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$, then

$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x \to 0^-}f(x)=f(0)
$$

So, the problem is solved if we know how to find :
$$
\lim_{x \to0} \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(1-\cos(1-\tan(\frac{\pi}{4}-x)))(1+x)^n+\lambda\sin((n-\sqrt{n^2-8n})x)}{x^2(1+x)^n+x}
$$
So, I thought of substituting $x=\frac{1}{n}$ and tried to solve the resulting limit. I'm not confident that this substitution is a valid step and was not able to solve the limit.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Since there's already an $n$ in your function, you should avoid using $\dfrac1n$ (because you probably want a sequence tending to 0, thus you should call it $\dfrac1k$). Anyway, this isn't sufficient to ensure the existence and the value of the limit. But do you know either L'Hospital rule or Taylor expansions? If yes, use them (your function seems so ugly that I don't see any other way to find the limit).

Comment: @paf This might be a little stupid, but I actually did mean $\frac{1}{n}$, because I figured since I knew $x \to 0$ and $n \to \infty$, why not just set $x=\frac{1}{n}$ and replace it with one variable and one limit constraint $x \to 0$. I didn't know if I was allowed to do this and your reply makes it clear that I'm not. Yes, I know both, I tried using the L'Hospital rule to simplify the limit but did not succeed. I'll look into the Taylor expansions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\tan(\tfrac\pi4-x)=\tan\tfrac\pi 4-\frac1{\cos^2\frac\pi4}\cdot x+O(x^2)=1-2x+O(x^2),$$
$$1- \cos(1-\tan(\tfrac \pi4-x))=1-\cos(2x+O(x^2)) =2x^2+O(x^3).$$
At least this is $\ne0$ for $x$ sufficiently close to $0$, i.e., there exists $r>0$ such that $1- \cos(1-\tan(\tfrac \pi4-x))\ne 0$ for $0<|x|<r$. Hence for fixed $x$ with $0<|x|<r$, 
the first summand in the numerator in the definition of $f(x)$ goes $\to\infty$ as $n\to \infty$, whereas the other summand is bounded by $\lambda$. Similarly, the first summand in the denominator dominates the other summand as $n\to\infty$. We conclude that for $x$ with $0<|x|<r$  we have
$$\begin{align} f(x)&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1- \cos(1-\tan(\tfrac \pi4-x)))(1+x)^n+\lambda\sin((n-\sqrt{n^2-8n})x)}{x^2(1+x)^n+x}\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1- \cos(1-\tan(\tfrac \pi4-x)))(1+x)^n}{x^2(1+x)^n}\\&=\frac{1- \cos(1-\tan(\tfrac \pi4-x))}{x^2}\\
&=2+O(x).\end{align}$$
Note that $f$ does not depend on $\lambda$ (at least for such $x$)
We conclude that
$$ f(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=2.$$